# Crystal Report Char With 2 Lines

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Line chart inside a report that was made by crystal report, the chart has only one line for sales per month

I need to make another line that reflects the targets of each month

how to do that?

PS: I get the chart data from certain table in my database and I've grouped the data by months
that's mean data appears in the graph like JAN/FEB/MAR ...etc

Comment: From where are you getting data for the graph?

Comment: @Siva, I get it from certain Table in my Database, Main post was edited